# XBOX 360 Controller Check if Button Pressed in C#

Tags: c#, xna, controller, xbox360, gamepad

I want to check in my C# project if the A Button of my Xbox 360 Controller is pressed. I've tried XNA and slimDX but it won't work. Can someone give me advice how it probably
will work?

Comment: **Show what you've tried**. What didn't work? Explain with detail!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Qhat did you try? Show some code, otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: Is it definitely plugged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in XNA

```
GamePadState currentState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);

if (currentState.IsConnected && currentState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
{

}
```